# Admin SDK Email setting API to delegate Email

Tags: google-email-settings-api, google-admin-sdk

I am looking for email delegation using google admin sdk.
I am using admin sdk because still its not available in Gmail API.

I checked google doc

> https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#delegation_examples

But it gives only feed url.

Can anyone please let me know how to call feedURl using Java code.
Or is there any api with can be used to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the legacy libraries, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321745/google-email-settings-api-using-oauth-2-0-service-account-in-java/28335129#28335129)

Comment: Thanks I could solve it using code available in GmailSettingsService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded GmailSettingsService of package sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings and modified it according to my need.